# Generate an Auto Increment Key Code using a TextView in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application where in a certain activity can generate a Key Code and will increment whenever the user comes back to that activity.

```
<LinearLayout>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_KeyCode"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
       android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_Remarks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
           android:layout_width="60dp"
           android:layout_height="25dp"
           android:background="@drawable/selector_button_gray"
           android:text="@string/save"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="15sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_Submit"
           android:layout_width="60dp"
           android:layout_height="25dp"
           android:background="@drawable/selector_button_gray"
           android:text="@string/submit"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="15sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_Cancel"
           android:layout_width="60dp"
           android:layout_height="25dp"
           android:background="@drawable/selector_button_gray"
           android:text="@string/cancel" 
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I generate code from my **TextView Key Code (e.g. 13-T012, 13-T013, 13-T014)** and make it auto increment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the value in preferences:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key_code", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int code = sp.getInt("code",0);

    if(code <= 0){
        code = 1; //--set default start value--
    }else{
        code++; //--or just increment it--
    }

    sp.edit().putInt("code",code).commit(); //--save new value--

    //--use code variable now--
    String newKey = "13-T0" + code;
```

You can place this code in `onStart()` of activity.

Comment: How can I restrict the incrementation of the code if I click the cancel button?

Comment: @RanmaMarquee move the `sp.edit()....commit()` part to `onClickListener` of save button.